# how to install nividia bumbulbee in linux mint 17.1 (cinnamon)?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, nvidia, cinnamon

I am having **Nvidia GEFORCE 610m** graphic card.

whenever i install nvidia drivers in mint cinnamon 17.1 my cinnamon crashes and my cinnamon goes in fallback mode !!

SO how can i install **bumblebee** in Mint 17.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** instead of 331 version, check what's current version of `nvidia-current` package. You can install it and see the version or just google this name and your distribution to check what's in repositories.

Have you followed this steps?

1) Open a terminal.
Install Bumblebee and the NVIDIA driver:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia bbswitch-dkms primus nvidia-331
```

2) Change Bumblebee’s configuration:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

3) Edit the lines so they match the lines below:

`[driver-nvidia]`

`KernelDriver=nvidia-`**331**

`LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-`**331**`:/usr/lib32/nvidia-`**331**

`XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-`**331**`/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules`

4) Save the file

5) Restart your computer

6) Test if it’s working (you should get a high FPS):

```
vblank_mode=0 glxgears
```

Comment: I assume this 331 is a different number depending on your system? Or whatever is the latest available?

Comment: I have nvidia-304 installed. I think this came from nvidia-current. nvidia-340 is also available.

Comment: Yes, when I wrote this answer, 331 was the latest version. I'll change my answer to be up-to-date.

Comment: The settings I already have say "nvidia-current" everywhere instead of "nvidia-331". I suppose this also works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - crashing and getting an error about Xclient or Xserver after installing nvidia. I had to remove nvidia to get the system working again. I figured out a fix. I recommend doing this before you even try to install the nvidia drivers:

In Mint go to Menu, then Administration, then Login Window. In Login Window Preferences select Options. At the top, the Default session is probably Run Xclient script. Change it to Cinnamon. Then reboot. Then install your nvidia and it should work.